# previou and/or parent not working in JS

Tags: javascript

The following is my objective :

The image is clicked, it shows the span "info_armes" wich contains the "X" button. Clicking the image again won't do anything, but clicking the "X" button will hide the button and the span "info_armes".

And well, what i've tried.. is simply not working.

HTML
`<u class="suj_i_i"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/KvYiINV.png" alt="M- AKM" title="M- AKM"></u>`

JS
/doesn't work here for some reason/

» https://jsfiddle.net/zg8Lx0qr/5/

Any idea ? Thanks.

Comment: No idea anyone ? /struggles/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove your inline style for display property (you already defined display in css):

```
$('img[alt="M- AKM"]').before('<span class="info_armes">Test <div class="xx">x</div></span>');
});
```

Problem was that your inline display style has precedence, so there was no change when you add class.

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/zg8Lx0qr/7/

Comment: Thank you mate, this was actually quite stupid from me but yeah, I don't seem to be able to guess this kind of mistake by myself. Thanks again.

Comment: Np, glad to help, we all make mistakes. :)